# How do I get json output from a date value from mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, highcharts

I am collecting stock market data periodically and I am storing in mongodb using pymongo as:

```
db.apple_stock.insert({'time': datetime.datetime.utcnow(), 'price': price})
```

Now I want the output in JSON format so that I can use highstocks:

```
[
    [1403546401372, 343], 
    [1403560801637, 454], 
    [1403575202199, 345], 
    [1403618402379, 345]
]
```

The Tornado is running on the server and 'mysite.com/api/stock.json' should provide above data in JSON file.

So, I query my database and used pymongo's [json_util](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html) to dump in json:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
dumps(query_result)
```

I am getting output as:

```
[
    [{"$date": 1403546401372}, 343], 
    [{"$date": 1403560801637}, 454], 
    [{"$date": 1403575202199}, 353]]
]
```

So how do I change the first item from dictionary to date, containing only value part? Is there any function available which does it or do I have to iterate through list and convert it myself?

secondly, if I really have to iterate the list, then what is the proper way of storing in MongoDB so that I get required output directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dumps` functionality is deliberately supplied in the pymongo driver utilities in order to provide what is known as [extended JSON format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

The purpose of this is to provide "type fidelity" where JSON itself is not aware of strict "types" such as what the BSON format is desinged for, and what MongoDB itself uses. It allows the transfer of JSON to clients that "may" be able to understand the "types" presented, such as "$date" or "$oid" and then use those keys to "de-serialize" the JSON into a specific "type" under that language specification.

What you will find "otherwise" with a standard form of JSON encode under most language implementations, is either:

- An interesting tuple of the time values
- A string representing the time value
- An epoch timestamp representing the time value

The best case for "custom serialization" is to either iterate the returned structure and implement serialization of the types yourself. Or to just use `dumps` form along with a "decode" of the JSON and then remove those "keys" identifying the "type".

Or of course just live with the base JSON encode outside of the special library and it's results.

The proper BSON date types that result in this are the "proper" way of storing in MongoDB. The usage of the library function is "by design". But the final way you use this is actually up to you.